# Event listener in Fiori List line item action

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement where I need to listen to a line item action of Fiori List elements report.

I have embedded Fiori list component 'L' inside a freestyle app component 'F 'because I need to display multiple independent reports in app 'F'.

Compoent F (Freestyle)
   embeds component L (List report created from Web IDE List report template).

Component 'L' has a line item action defined upon which I need to update an element which is part of component 'F'. The action is achieved by BOPF action.
The local annotation will be something like below:

```
`<Record Type="UI.DataFieldForAction">
     <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="AddToCart"/>
     <PropertyValue Property="Action"
        String="some_Entities/actionAddToCart"/>
     <PropertyValue Property="Inline" Bool="true"/>
     <Annotation Term="UI. InvocationGrouping"
        EnumMember="UI.OperationGroupingType/Isolated"/>
  </Record>`
```

How do I know when the action gets completed so that I can update the element value in component 'F'? Precisely, I need to show the number of items in cart after user adds a line item to cart through BOPF action. So I need to capture the action 'completed' event and read the count from OData again.

Regards.

Sumit

Comment: Could you please post some code examples of what you have tried to accomplish here?

Comment: I have not implemented it yet. But implementing the line item action will be iin linen with SAP official documentation https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw751abap/7.51.0/de-DE/b6/23e0bbbb2b4147b2d0516c463921a0/frameset.htm.